# to read a string obtained from server in XML format in android

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-widget

I am having URL of PHP file from where i am getting all data in XML format.
Now i am able to read all those data using InputStream and passing to buffer.But the problem is i am not getting how can i separate all required data from the available data.I tried using DOM but it is giving me following error in my log

```
`Error in http connection java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found in android
```

The code i am using is as follow.

```
try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new
                        HttpPost("http://www.mbusiness.com/mobile.php?id="+id.trim());
                HttpResponse response;
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                data = new byte[256];
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = is.read(data)) )
                  {
                     buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                  }
                Log.e("log_tag",""+buffer.toString());

                 //Make the comparison case-insensitive.
                is.close();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(buffer.toString());
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Log.e("Log.Tag",""+doc);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }
```

My PHP file which i am reading is giving me following details

```
   <profile>
    <details user_login="chirag" 
user_nickname="chirag" 
user_email="dipendra@bcod.co.in" 
display_name="chirag" 
first_name="chirag singh" 
last_name="test singh" 
nickname="chirag singh" 
description="" 
twitter_id="" 
facebook_id="" 
paypal_email="" 
business_name="My Business Test" 
business_abn="testabn" 
business_contact="Chirag Test" 
business_phone="123456789" 
business_fax="123456" 
business_mobile="1456789" 
business_emailss="chirag@gmail.com" 
business_facebookzz="http://www.facebook.com" 
business_linkedin="http://www.linkedin.com" 
business_myspace="http://myspacelink.com" 
business_blog="Blog" 
business_im="im" 
business_website="tester" 
business_street="TestStreet" 
business_city="TestCity" 
business_postcode="123456" 
business_state="NSW New South Wales" 
business_trading="12345" 
business_area="500" 
business_trade="Saturday" 
business_products="TesterProducts" 
business_services="testerservices" 
business_delivery="only sunday" 
redirect_to=""/>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Hi Parth, Before you pass the values to the buffer, you need to check that they are not null.

Comment: Yeah i am doing that using for loop in my program.But that nt my problem over here my problem is something different @how to differentiate the value which i am getting from a PHP file

Comment: ok, got it, from the above reading list, which value you want read ?

Comment: Actually i want to read all values and set it in my Layout where i have use edittext for all the above values.Basically i am generating a profile page where i wanted to display data of users to them so that they can edit them and post my other URL back

Comment: ok it is possible using two simple loops & StringTokenizer Class, one more question, are you getting reply in this list format or in continues format ?

Comment: In continues format..By the way what is StringTokenizer class..can u please help me by giving some example.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There go your DOM parser: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/android-xml-adventure-%e2%80%93-parsing-xml-data-with-dom/

Comment: thnks sir for wonderful tutorial it really gave me idea to solve some part of my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The [parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method of DocumentBuilder is expecting an URL as the parameter, not the XML content as a String. You can simplify your code by directly passing the InputStream to the parse method without any buffering:

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: 11-25 15:55:07.250: ERROR/log_tag(573): Error in http connection org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document

Comment: can u please give me some suggestion for the above problem

Comment: Thnks buddy for helping me but i used SAXparser to solve my issue.